# Getting an ID out of a string. Regex problem

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the ID from a URL string.

I'm trying with the following code:-

FROM:

```
<url>http://www.monkeys.com/monkey.php?id=24</url>
```

I want to get '24' with:-

```
$ID = preg_replace($url, '/^<url>.*\?id=(.*)<\/url>$/', '\1');
```

Any help would be much appreciated - i'm sure this is a regular problem, but I find regex baffling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is the wrong tool for the job. Use

- [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) — *Parses the string into variables* and
- [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) — *Parse a URL and return its components*

Example:

```
$url = "http://www.monkeys.com/monkey.php?id=24";
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $parts);
var_dump( $parts ); // 24
```

Getting the URL out of the `<URL>` element should be trivial. [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is your friend. See the various other questions dealing with [Reading XML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Reading+XML+with+PHP) and also this article why you [should not use Regex for parsing HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: For some reason, I'm not getting it...

$url = http://www.test.com/tester.php?id=212

parse_str($url, $parts);

echo $parts['id'] = nothing.

Comment: Works now, didn't follow your example properly. :/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex:

```
/^[^?]+\?id=(.*).*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID is numeric only :

```
/\?id=(\d+)/
```

If there's nothing after ID

```
/\?id=(.*)/
```

Comment: What if there's another argument after it?

Comment: @Wim: it depends of OP's string, it could be  
/\?id=(.*?)&?/

Comment: Yes, `/\?id=(.*?)&?/` would be the most general solution.

Comment: and much more accurate is : /\?|&id=(.*?)&?/