# Get the GET variables from a URL String

Tags: php, variables, get

Hey, say I have a url just being passed through my php is there any easy way to get some GET variables that are being passed through it? It's not the actual url of the page or anything.

like a just have a string containing

http://www.somesite.com/index.php?url=var&file_id=var&test=var

Whats the best way to get the values for those variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an ID out of a string. Regex problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131288/getting-an-id-out-of-a-string-regex-problem) - see accepted answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $array)`, see the [manpage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for parse_str for more info.

Answer (score 16):

```
$href = 'http://www.somesite.com/index.php?url=var&file_id=var&test=var';

$url = parse_url($href);
print_r($url);
/* Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.somesite.com
    [path] => /index.php
    [query] => url=var&file_id=var&test=var
) */

$query = array();
parse_str($url['query'], $query);

print_r($query);
/* Array
(
    [url] => var
    [file_id] => var
    [test] => var
) */
```

Comment: Does not seem to work if you have a CSS instead of PHP file. Might be doing something wrong.

Comment: php code never works in css files (unless you have registered css files to be application/x-httpd-php or equivalent in your server configuration, which you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Yes I understand. What I meant to say is that I have a CSS file referred with `style.css?v=12345`, v being a version number to force a refresh of the cache browser side. What I wanted to do was remove or extract the parameter. Got it working the way I want now.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a lot easier than writing any custom functions.

$queryStr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

Comment: that takes both get and post vars, right? In that case you might end up with a lot more arguments than just the get vars from the URL. If you in stead use REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING then you only get the args from URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like:

```
preg_match_all('/(\?|&)([^=]+=[^&]*)/', $string , $matches);
```

then

```
print_r($matches[2]);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => url=var
    [1] => file_id=var
    [2] => test=var
)
*/
```

Hope it works 4 u.

Answer (score -1):

A quick google for "PHP GET" gives this page from w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Comment: He's not asking about retrieving the parameters of the current page.  Rather, he wants to parse the query string from some arbitrary URL, i.e. from some string.