# Regex, how to match this string?

Tags: php, regex, url

I have the url `http://domain.com/script.php?l=7&p=146#p146`. I want to be able to get the number after p=, without the #. Also, the hash may not always be there, so sometimes it could turn out as `script.php?l=7&p=146`. I know it's something to do with the regex character `+`, but I'm not completely sure on how to use it. Can someone please create the regex and explain how it works?

Comment: There are much better ways to do this than regex.

Comment: Can you please post an answer with a better way? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) ?

Comment: any solution for a problem that calls for a regex now has two problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136425/get-the-get-variables-from-a-url-string

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse who says that the URL is actually the URL of the request and not just some string?

Answer (score 5):

No need for regular expressions here.

```
$query = parse_url("http://domain.com/script.php?l=7&p=146#p146", PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);
echo $params['p'];
```

`parse_url` can get you all the distinct elements of a URL. And `parse_str` takes a query string (that stuff you find between `?` and an optional `#` in a URL) and figures out the different parameters for you. You could also omit the parameter `$params` to the function, then `parse_str` would define some variables for you (afterward you could find the result in `$p`). But I personally rather dislike using `parse_str` with this side effect.

If you want to read up some more: PHP documentation on [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a built-in function, such as `parse_url` to parse the URL.

Documentation and examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php