# remove part of url from google API

Tags: php, regex

Google API

provides this kind of links

http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNFhnbiaA4JmbJdwKBzJOxs2B49LfQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&ei=eBZlU8CyBIWc1QajIA*&url=*http://opinion.inquirer.net/74164/aseans-elusive-integration

how can I get just the link after "&url=" ?

Answer

```
$link = '...a4878e06b80cf16b898331&ei=eBZlU8CyBIWc1QajIA*&url=http://opinion.inquirer.net/74164/aseans-elusive-integration';
$parsed = parse_url($link);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($parsed).'</pre>';
```

This should show the url from the &url= parameter in the last position of the string.
hope it helps

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Why try when you can it for free here?

Comment: @Flynn- please don't change your question after it has been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use the [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) functions. You can use this to separate the string information to find a certain parameter value.

```
parse_str(parse_url($urlString, PHP_URL_QUERY), $array)
```

All of the parameters would be stored in the $array variable.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136450/2748747

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, enjoy.

```
<?php
$str = 'http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNFhnbiaA4JmbJdwKBzJOxs2B49LfQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&ei=eBZlU8CyBIWc1QajIA&url=http://opinion.inquirer.net/74164/aseans-elusive-integration';

$str = preg_split('/&/', $str);

$final = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($str); $i++ ){
    $a = preg_split('/=/', $str[$i]);
    if(is_array($a)) {
        $final[$a[0]] = $a[1];
    }
}


var_dump($final);

echo $final['url'];
```