# PHP extract from string

Tags: php, regex, string, extract

I have a string that has a url with variables in it for example:

```
http://www.example.com/?foo=example1&foo1=example2&foo2=example3
```

I'm quite new to PHP and when looking through the delimiters and modifiers, I can't quite get my head around how to apply them properly to my situation without getting some sort of error.
I was wondering whether someone could point me in the right direction on how to extract "foo1" into a variable of it's own for use else where. I would need to extract the data between "&foo1=" and the following "&".

This is what I have (incorrect delimiters/modifiers):

```
("&foo1=[^&]+?\&'", $getData))
```

So how could I fix this up to extract the data for "foo1" perhaps?

**Edit:** This URL with the variable(s) I need is WITHIN a STRING, not as a URL itself and it is an external link. The variables aren't always in URL form either, they are often just in the string as the variables like so:

```
foo=example1&foo1=example2&foo2=example3
```

So from a string like that, how would I extract the value of "foo1"?

Comment: `$_GET['foo1']` and `$_GET['foo2']`

Comment: Are you asking to better understand the regex for this, or are you actually needing to extract the key/value pairs? There's much easier ways to do so.

Comment: Is it your website so you want to extract the variables you get? or a URL you want to parse and get these variables?

Comment: PHP has all kinds of functions built in, including url and query string parsing. I suggest you check those first before writing your own (unless it's for learning purposes only).

Comment: Trying to use regular expressions for parsing is a fruitless endeavour. Lucky or you there are functions [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for this *exact* case.

Comment: The URL is WITHIN a text string, and the values of foo1 are different in every string I'll be passing to it, I can't use URL parsing as the URL isn't actually in use with the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the GET variables from a URL String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136425/get-the-get-variables-from-a-url-string) or [Getting an ID out of a string. Regex problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131288/getting-an-id-out-of-a-string-regex-problem) - If you refer to other questions / answers, please make clear what exactly did not work for you. That will explain why you need to ask another question here on site and will improve your question so that you will recieve better answers.

Answer (score 5):

First [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) it, then pass the query part to [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$url ="http://www.example.com/?foo=example1&foo1=example2&foo2=example3";
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$query = array();
parse_str($parsedUrl['query'],$query);
var_dump($query);

-- array (
  'foo' => 'example1',
  'foo1' => 'example2',
  'foo2' => 'example3',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however the values of the variables are different each time and I need to grab "foo1" out of the middle of the string and put it in a variable in PHP for use. Other answers have suggested to parse it as a URL, however, I didn't mention (I should have), that it isn't always in URL form within the strings, the variables are often held within it as just "foo=example1&foo1=example2&foo2=example3".

Answer (score 0):

Is it *your* website? Do you want to know what the values passed were?
`$_GET['...']`.

Else, if you want to *parse* a URL, and extract the variables,

`preg_match_all('/([^?&=#]+)=([^&#]*)/', $url, $matches);`

Comment: Using a regex to parse a URL is a very bad solution. PHP has built in functions for parsing URLs as the the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15799352/1592648) has demonstrated.

Answer (score -2):

Just expanding on "Class"'s answer to help you understand, something like `?foo=example1` means that `foo` is a variable with value `example1`.

in php, to get these values from the url, just use `$_GET['myvariablename']`, in your case, it will be

```
$var1 = $_GET['example1'];
$var2 = $_GET['example2'];
$var3 = $_GET['example3'];
```

Comment: The variables are in a string, there is lots of text and then a link that changes with a different value for "foo1" each time. I can't use $_GET since it isn't a URL that is in use for the script.